# How to set the Componenets in Horizontal Manager in Blackberry?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

Can any one tell me how to set a componenets in a particular position in horizontal layout manager in blackberry.If u can provide me some code snippet.
regards,
s.kumaran.

Comment: Did you mean "component" perhaps? I had almost edited your article, but then noticed that you use "componenets" twice, so perhaps that's a term I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the HorizontalFieldManager and override the sublayout method.  Within this method you can call setPositionChild and layoutChild for each component that you want to add and define the size and position of each.